# what does getter documents[docslen] isnt defined for the type 'Map<String, dynamic> Function() mean?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
getDocs() async {
  final QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Donation').where('blood_group', isEqualTo: SelectedValueOutput).get();
  final List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> documentSnapshotList = querySnapshot.docs;


    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot snapshot in documentSnapshotList) {
      for(int docsLen in snapshot.data().values) {
      int lengthOfItemCount = snapshot.data().length;
      return new ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        itemCount: lengthOfItemCount,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int length) {
          return Card(
            child: Text(snapshot.data.documents[docsLen]['recovered_date'].toString()),
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }
}
```

the error i am getting is:

> The getter 'documents' isn't defined for the type 'Map<String, dynamic> Function()'.

i don't know why is it saying that when this guy did it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2KknXzalXfg&t

what i want to do is get all values where blood group is selected value(A+,A-,....) and then show me all data where selected value(A+,A-,....) is

Comment: getter `documents` is deprecated in favor `docs` (see Migration guide here https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration/ ). Youtube video you mentioned is outdated, firestore api had some minor api changes since then. You can take a look here how firestore propper calls are made now - https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage

Comment: That looks like an answer @SimonSot! :) 